# Implement p-mean in excel

Tags: excel, average

I'm spreadsheeting my favorite albums and I'd like the good tracks on the album to count more for its average than the bad songs. I thought about geometric means, but those do the opposite of what I want.

I found the p-mean, which approaches the maximum of the dataset as p goes to infinity:
[image]

Is there any way to implement this formula in only one cell? If p=2, I can use `sqrt(sumsq())` but I'm not sure how to implement it if p > 2. It's impractical for me to add adjacent cells in each column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I ended up doing it:

```
=(SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(E2:E99),E2:E99^N))/COUNT(E2:E99))^(1/N)
```

This is an array formula, so it must be entered with ctrl + shift + enter rather than just enter.

[Credit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59060440/7583953) goes to Scott Craner.