# How to create a function in excel for sum of cubes or higher powers?

Tags: excel, average

I'm trying to implement p-means, as laid out in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59046952/impliment-p-mean-in-excel)

If p=2, I can do `SQRT(SUMSQ(data))`.

If p=3, I need to do `CBRT(**SUM OF CUBES**(data))`

And so on. The first part is easy to scale, I can just raise the whole thing to `1/N`. But how would I implement sum of cubes, fourth powers, etc. ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "But how would I implement sum of cubes, fourth powers, etc."?

With SUMPRODUCT:

If your data is in `A1:A3` for example:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A3^3)

=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A3^4)
```

etc.

[image]

I'd ditch the use of `SUMSQ` here and just use `SUMPRODUCT` all around.

> This causes an error if any non-numbers are present (such as `-`), while the `SUMSQ()` method does not. Is there any way to do this such that non-numbers (or just `-`) are ignored?

One option is with `IFERROR`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(--$A$1:$A$4,0)^C1)
```

[image]

Comment: This causes an error if any non-numbers are present (such as `-`), while the `SUMSQ()` method does not. Is there any way to do this such that non-numbers (or just `-`) are ignored?

Answer (score 0):

Scott's answer to [another question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59060385/ignore-text-with-sumproduct) is what I ended up using:

```
=(SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(E2:E99),E2:E99^3))/COUNT(E2:E99))^(1/3)
```

This is an array formula (ctrl + shift + enter or it won't work).