# Ignore text with SUMPRODUCT

Tags: excel, sumproduct

I'm using `SUMPRODUCT()` to calculate the p-mean of data where p=3:

```
=(SUMPRODUCT(E2:E99^3)/COUNT(E2:E99))^(1/3)
```

There are `-`'s mixed into the data. How can I ignore them so as not to get a value error and still get the correct answer (as if the `-`'s weren't there)?

Comment: Is `E2:E99^3` a valid range?

Comment: Yes, the formula works on ranges of only numbers. It cubes every number, sums them, divides by the count, then finds the cube root.

Comment: I just added an answer to your last question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To deal with non numbers in the range use this array formula:

```
=(SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(E2:E99),E2:E99^3))/COUNT(E2:E99))^(1/3)
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]